# Deployment in Webmatrix to IIS 7 removes Rewrite Rules

Tags: deployment, iis-7, url-rewriting

We are using Webmatrix to host and test (locally) our Silverlight 4 app that is hosted in a asp.net web app. The Silverlight client also calls a WCF service on the web app.

We want to take the app to production and deploy it in IIS 7 ( We are using Discount Asp).
We used the FTP deploy from within Webmatrix and it deployed the app successfully. The problem is that this operation cleans all the Rewrite Rules that we defined on the IIS server on Discount ASP.

When we want to update the Silverlight client, we can work around this and avoid using the FTP deploy on webmatrix, and instead just manually copy the replace the new XAP file. This works fine.

But if we want to update the server, for example add new method to the service, Just copying and replacing the Service.svc , Service.svc.cs and IService.cs won't do the trick.
The new methods can't be seen and the client can't use them (Trying to Add Service Reference from VS won't show the new methods either).

So:
1) Why using FTP Deploy from Webmatrix cleans all the rewrite rules ?

2) Is it possible to use the work around and update the WCF service ?